# Limit Java Heap Space for play framework globaly

Tags: java, playframework

I have a very old linux system and installed java and play framework. When I run java I get:

```
java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

So I limited the java heap space in application.conf:

```
jvm.memory=-Xmx256M -Xms256M
```

With that setting I can run play test, play run etc....

But I cannot run:

```
play dependencies 
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.1, http://www.playframework.org
~
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Is there a global configuration file or environment variable where I can limit java heap space globaly for play framework?

**Update:**
Also the following is not working:

```
play dependencies -Xmx256M -Xms256M
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.1, http://www.playframework.org
~
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

**Update 2**:

Memory:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1024
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 38912
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Limits:

```
cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:      4139312 kB
MemFree:        332988 kB
Buffers:        105252 kB
Cached:        1705644 kB
SwapCached:          4 kB
Active:        2566216 kB
Inactive:       625032 kB
HighTotal:      786432 kB
HighFree:         1728 kB
LowTotal:      3352880 kB
LowFree:        331260 kB
SwapTotal:     4192956 kB
SwapFree:      4168224 kB
Dirty:             368 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
Mapped:        1672180 kB
Slab:           570864 kB
CommitLimit:   6262612 kB
Committed_AS:  4075144 kB
PageTables:      19884 kB
VmallocTotal:   303096 kB
VmallocUsed:     10400 kB
VmallocChunk:   292648 kB
```

BR,

Rene

Comment: please note that -Xmx/-Xms denote the amount of _heap_ memory used, the total amount of memory used will be much much higher.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After googling more around I found [this](http://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=7057) discussion. The problem is, that my Linux System is running in an openvz container:

*The reason why Java complains is because on start up, it sees that the machine has more than 2 GB of RAM, so it starts up in server mode, which tries to allocate all the memory, which then fails because it is inside a VPS.*

I could fix the java startup problem by changing /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/i386/jvm.cfg from:

```
-client IF_SERVER_CLASS -server
-server KNOWN
-hotspot ALIASED_TO -client
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

to:

```
#-client IF_SERVER_CLASS -server
-client KNOWN
-server KNOWN
-hotspot ALIASED_TO -client
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

Now I can run any play command. Maybe this helps other people having similar problems related to container based virtualization.

BR, Rene

Comment: Wow, how did you find out? You saved my life :)

Comment: I'm on a VPS, but this didn't fix my problem. :(

Comment: +1 I am on a citrix-something, so this is most def going to help me!

Comment: Newer releases (1.7.0_40 on x64 in my case) don't appear to have the client JVM anymore. Stuck on server I suppose. Bumer

Answer (score 24):

Play does not appear to pick up the jvm.memory settings for dependencies or even test command.  One way to force it to use specific JVM settings would be to use _JAVA_OPTIONS.

For example:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms800m -Xmx1500m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
play test
```

or

```
play deps
```

and you should see

```
~        _            _ 
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/   
~
~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
~ framework ID is test
~
~ Running in test mode
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms800m -Xmx1500m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

Note that this would apply those settings to all java programs run on that terminal where _JAVA_OPTIONS is set.

Comment: In Play 1.2.4, the environment variable seems to be JAVA_OPTS

Comment: @itsadok: Actually this seems to be more of a Java Runtime thing than Play specific. If you set _JAVA_OPTIONS and run "java -version", you'll see that the settings are picked up.

Comment: I guess we're talking about two completely different mechanisms. I was referring to [this](https://github.com/playframework/play/commit/bfb715eac9b89e537c21349dc3868d141bf55bf1).

Comment: how about Play 2.2.0?

Comment: Setting this gives me "No java installations was detected.
Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download" error.

Answer (score 12):

Normally, you can specify Java command line arguments when you call play using the following pattern.

```
play run <appname> -Xmx256M -Xms256M
```

However, looking at the python code for the `play run` command and the `play dependencies` command, they invoke Java in different ways.

The play dependencies command invokes Java without passing through -X commands (for some reason, it passes through -D commands, but not -X). Therefore, there is nothing you can do, apart from editing the `deps.py`  file in framework/pym/play/commands and hard coding the -Xmx and -Xms settings into this file.

This not a long term solution, and I would suggest you raise a ticket on Play to allow these settings to be read from command line, or from the application.conf, but for now, I see this approach as your only option.

Comment: Post updated. I have looked at the python code, and can now see exactly your problem,

Comment: Thanks, I hardcoded it and also created a ticket. The same problem is for evolutions :-(

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this on my laptop running Fedora and using Play 2.0 when simply starting the interactive shell. I found that the build script is setting the memory values by default to pretty high values.

To fix this I had to edit the `$play_dir/framework/build` script and change the values manually, at the end of the script it does the following to launch:

```
java ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M ...
```

Just change the -Xmx/-Xms values (and possibly the permgen) accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You computer doesn't have enough RAM to run Java. Java needs at least 64MB RAM.

Note that you can't add free memory to your computer by specifying `-Xms` to Java: Java can't add memory modules to your mainboard. `-Xms` just tells Java how much of the available RAM to take. If that fails (= the OS returns an error when Java tries to allocate it), you get the error above.

My guess is that there is no swap space. Look at the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`. Or you have a `ulimit` set which limits how much memory each process can allocate (try `ulimit -a` to check).

Comment: See Update 2. There is still swap space left and almost 1 GB Memory is used for caches.

Comment: That's really odd. Try to invoke `java -version -Xmx32M` (with only 32MB or even less). As long as you can't start `java` itself, `play` won't work.

Comment: See my answer. The problem was, that java is running in a container.

Answer (score 3):

In Play 2.2 and Java 7, this is what I used.

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/foo -mem 256 -J-server
```

For the detail of -mem, please see:

```
$ target/universal/stage/bin/foo -h
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `play` command you run is actually a Python script which invokes other Play Framework python modules, which eventually invoke the `java` command as subprocess.

Looking at [the source code for the code that runs](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/pym/play/commands/deps.py) for the `dependencies` command, there doesn't appear to be any logic to load an environment variable or anything else to specify the max heap size as the `-Xmx` argument. In other words, the Python code from Play which invokes the JVM in this script has no way to specify the max heap size from the default.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Try increasing --XX:MaxHeapSize to a higher allocation. Here is my configuration in path/to/framework/build

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1300M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m...
```

Answer (score 0):

Play does not recognize -XX options. Instead use -DX.