# Does 'play start' support JVM command line options?

Tags: playframework

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6763527/11236) that in order to pass JVM switches to play, you append them to `play run`, e.g.

```
play run -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,jregex/Pretokenizer,next
```

Does the same trick work with `play start` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably. But even better, you can directly call Play via the java command line as is done in IntelliJ.

```
java play.server.Server -Dapplication.path=/path/to/my/application -Dplay.id=myplayid
```

Comment: play run is a wrapper around it. Thus having default options. As your wish seems to be to customize those parameters a start from scratch seems more adapted. Close to the talk about Gentoo and other linux distros. If you build it yourself, it is better for your use. ;)