# Deploying Playframework 2 to AppFog - Memory problems

Tags: deployment, playframework, cloud, playframework-2.0, appfog

I am trying to deploy simple Playframework Scala app to AppFog. I've created new Scala application and added a JAR from [AppFog documentation](https://docs.appfog.com/languages/java/play). Then I've followed the steps from [deploying to AppFog guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/Deploying-CloudFoundry).

The problem is that the application won't start when less than 900MB of memory is reserved. The error is :

```
    Error: Application [pralab-test] failed to start, logs information below.
    ====> /logs/stdout.log <====

    No database found in Play configuration.  Skipping auto-reconfiguration.
    Play server process ID is 13276
    [‹[33mwarn‹[0m] play - Plugin [org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.play.JPAPlugin]
    is disabled
    [‹[37minfo‹[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
    #
    # There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
    # pthread_getattr_np
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # /mnt/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/pralab-test-0-d6bc1b644e85148149d759499e02b409/ap
    p/hs_err_pid13276.log
```

When started with more memory application starts and uses only about 140MB of declared 900MB. Is it a startup memory peak of Play or there is a bug in AppFog?

Do you have any successful deployments of Play applications on AppFog?

**EDIT** 
This runs OK on cloudfoundry.com with 256M of memory.

Comment: I’m guessing that the problem here is something to do with JVM heap sizes (and that perhaps cloudfoundry.com uses different defaults). However, my attempt to set Java options, as inspired by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763453/limit-java-heap-space-for-play-framework-globaly that is, setting value of _JAVA_OPTIONS to specify lower heap sizes, worked on my local machine, but not when I uploaded to AppFog.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and couldn't get around it.  I just had to do what you did and allocate 1G to my app when it was only using around 250m.  I opened customer support ticket and got no response.

I believe you are having this same problem that they claim to have fixed for "JAVA" but must not be rolled out to play autodetected apps: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appfog-users/hxBxUe3c4QI

Current options are just live with more memory allocated.