# Out of memory in PlayFramework 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do I increase the memory available to the Play environment? I am running out of memory after a time while running tests.

In particular, I get this error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763453/limit-java-heap-space-for-play-framework-globaly The answer recommended in this thread might help

Answer (score 14):

I solved this problem by adding:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx2048M", "-Xms512M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M")
```

in Build.scala to the settings.

Comment: Setting a maximum of 2Gb to perm gen space is, at least, not knowing what perm gen means and postponing the problem to the future. You need to understand why your application is allocating so much class metadata...

Comment: @Jonathan that's not true for all use cases. My Play! app is running a PageRank algo across a 2 million edge Cassovary graph...it has every right to be allocated more perm gen. ;)

Comment: Isn't there a "-mem" flag that play supports?  I cannot find the documentation about this anywhere, but have seen it used before.

Answer (score 13):

By setting the environment variable "_JAVA_OPTIONS", you can pass in variables that play/sbt will use during normal use.  I found that this helped me avoid PermGen space errors when running my dev and tests.

For example:

export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Xss2m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Comment: upvote for environment variables. This is much more useful because it allows you to set these settings for different environments. we have a separate server for development and one for our production app and we don't need as much memory on our dev server. As well as considerations for our local dev environments.

Comment: Upvote except that the original question was about the PermGen space so the last argument needs to be MaxPermSize=256m

Answer (score 8):

The Java startup options for play are founder in the script:

> $PLAY_HOME/framework/build

The PermGen space can be increased by modifying the line at the bottom of the file:

> java ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M ...

Set the MaxPermSize variable to an appropriate value.