# Why Play Framework 2.5 doesn't respect JVM memory settings in sbt?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

So I've been struggling with setting memory settings with Play inside sbt with:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx11G", "-Xms3G")
```

But it seems like it's not respecting it.

When I print it

```
val mb = 1024*1024

//Getting the runtime reference from system
val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime

println("##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####")

//Print used memory
println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb)

//Print free memory
println("Free Memory:" + runtime.freeMemory() / mb)

//Print total available memory
println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb)

//Print Maximum available memory
println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb)
```

here is what I see:

```
##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####
Used Memory:270
Free Memory:657
Total Memory:928
Max Memory:928
```

I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695116/1164246) by setting `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, but the issue with this is that, it gives me the following error:

```
No java installations was detected.
Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
```

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Try `fork in run := true`, see [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html).

Comment: I have `fork in run := true`, which I suppose it subsumes `fork := true` right?

Comment: It depends on your system and JVM (are they both 32-bit, 64-bit). On 32-bit JVM you can't allocate that much memory(about 1G I think). That is where my knowledge about JVM Xmx ends.. xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Assuming `fork` is set to `true`) If you're using the Play application startup script in production mode, the [recommended way](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#JVM-configuration) is to pass them as command-line arguments to the script. Otherwise the default JVM settings will be used. Here you are working in dev mode using `sbt run` or `activator run`, so you need to effectively do the same.

**Solution 1:**

You can pass the arguments on command-line:

```
$ sbt run -J-Xms3G -J-Xmx11G
```

**Solution 2:**

Starting `sbt` 0.13.6, you can add `.sbtopts` file in your project root directory to set JVM flags. This is probably a nicer way because it makes your project self-contained.

Here's a sample `.sbtopts`:

```
-J-Xms3G
-J-Xmx11G
```

Here's the output of `$ sbt run` (or `activator run`):

```
##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####
Used Memory: 364
Free Memory: 4062
Total Memory: 4426
Max Memory: 10012
```

You can read more about the options and usage [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/master/src/universal/bin/sbt#L69-#L112).

Note: If this was an SBT project instead of Play, `javaOptions` defined in  `build.sbt` would apply directly.

Comment: These flags seem to be ignored when you've generated a binary from `sbt dist`?