# Play Framework 2.5 application crash without visible cause

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I've got an application that crashes with the following trace :

```
2017-03-22 16:47:15,637 - [[error]] - akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-79 - Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-77] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled -
2017-03-22 16:47:15,640 - [[debug]] - com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.ShutdownManager - Thread-3 - Shutting down -
2017-03-22 16:47:15,640 - [[debug]] - com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer - Thread-3 - Shutting down EbeanServer default -
```

The root cause of the error triggered by Akka is not provided ...

Is there any way to get the cause of this error?

Here is the logback file, if it is usefull ...

```
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>/home1/log/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%date - [%coloredLevel] - %logger - %thread - %message - %xException%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.asynchttpclient" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="akka" level="DEBUG" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using explicitly using the actor system somewhere? Or is there any memory leak on the application? Try to inspect how much memory your application is consuming.This is too generic error to identify the problem. I have had something similar and it was what I said.

Comment: Not myself, but I think that WSClient (that I use) has a memory leak somewhere (cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957966/play-framework-2-5-wsclient-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: Try to review all your implementation of WSClient https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS You can also increase the heap size of your application and then see if you get any clues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763453/limit-java-heap-space-for-play-framework-globaly My best guess is that your memory is too small to handle all the multiple requests at the same time. You may have a look into the configuration of your akka dispacher

Comment: Setting log level in logback is not enough to make Akka log at debug level. See [Logging section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/logging.html) in Akka configuration how to set up logging in `application.conf`.

Comment: I already increased the heap size, but the application keep crashing.

Comment: @MirMasej : The logback file I included was not the one I actually use, I had a logger for "play" and convinced myself that akka was logged in it. I updated my logback and still nothing in the logs

Comment: and I added akka.loggers, akka.loglevel, akka.logging-filter as explained in the doc you gave me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to get the cause exception was to run the application in development mode (unfortunately, the bug occurred only in production environment) to get the stacktrace in the console.

I created an issue to Akka to add logs about the cause exception : https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/22630